# Progress 4gl - change font color of specific values while exporting temp table to .html file

Tags: openedge, progress-4gl, 4gl

I have a situation where I would like to change the font color of the specific values in a temp table while exporting to .html using progress 4gl.

Below is the program I wrote to output the values to .html file.
Please help me to solve this.

```
OUTPUT TO VALUE ("JITS_UserMonitor\JITS_UserMonitor.html").
PUT UNFORMATTED "<TABLE
                    style=' border: 1px solid black;border-collapse: collapse;width:100%; font-family: arial, sans-serif;'>
                        <tr style='background-color: #dddddd; text-align: center' >
                            <th style=' border: 1px solid black;border-collapse: collapse;'>USER Name</th>
                            <th style=' border: 1px solid black;border-collapse: collapse;'>USER Full Name</th>
                            <th style=' border: 1px solid black;border-collapse: collapse;'>USER CREATE Date</th>
                            <th style=' border: 1px solid black;border-collapse: collapse;'>USER LastLogin Date</th>
                            <th style=' border: 1px solid black;border-collapse: collapse;'>Need Disable</th>
                            <th style=' border: 1px solid black;border-collapse: collapse;'>Need DELETE</th>
                            <th style=' border: 1px solid black;border-collapse: collapse;'>DISABLE Status</th>
                            <th style=' border: 1px solid black;border-collapse: collapse;'>LAST Logon Days</th>
                        </tr>
                    " SKIP.
    FOR EACH tt_data WHERE tt_data.tt_needdisable EQ TRUE OR 
            tt_data.tt_needdelete EQ TRUE NO-LOCK BY tt_data.tt_days DESC:
        PUT UNFORMATTED SUBSTITUTE ("   <tr style = 'text-align: center'>
                                                <td style=' border: 1px solid black;border-collapse: collapse;'>&1</td>
                                                <td style=' border: 1px solid black;border-collapse: collapse;'>&2</td>
                                                <td style=' border: 1px solid black;border-collapse: collapse;'>&3</td>
                                                <td style=' border: 1px solid black;border-collapse: collapse;'>&4</td>
                                                <td style=' border: 1px solid black;border-collapse: collapse;'>&5</td>
                                                <td style=' border: 1px solid black;border-collapse: collapse;'>&6</td>
                                                <td style=' border: 1px solid black;border-collapse: collapse;'>&7</td>
                                                <td style=' border: 1px solid black;border-collapse: collapse;'>&8</td>
                                            </tr>",
                                                tt_data.tt_userid,
                                                tt_data.tt_fullname,
                                                tt_data.tt_createddate,
                                                tt_data.tt_lastlogon, 
                                                tt_data.tt_needdisable,
                                                tt_data.tt_needdelete,
                                                tt_data.tt_disable,
                                                tt_data.tt_days) SKIP.
    END.    
PUT UNFORMATTED "</TABLE>" SKIP.
OUTPUT CLOSE.
```

Comment: Showing an example with a temp-table with eight fields does not make your example better, it just adds noise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `IF` inside your statement. Something like this:

```
PUT UNFORMATTED 'This will output ' (IF TRUE THEN "something" ELSE "nothing").
```

That will output

> This will output something

`TRUE` can be changed to any check you want to.

However, since you use `SUBSTITUTE` you could consider adding a variable for the color.

```
PUT UNFORMATTED SUBSTITUTE ("   <tr style = 'text-align: center'>
                                            <td style=' border: 1px solid black;border-collapse: collapse;color:&9;'>&1</td>
                                            <td style=' border: 1px solid black;border-collapse: collapse;'>&2</td>
                                            <td style=' border: 1px solid black;border-collapse: collapse;'>&3</td>
                                            <td style=' border: 1px solid black;border-collapse: collapse;'>&4</td>
                                            <td style=' border: 1px solid black;border-collapse: collapse;'>&5</td>
                                            <td style=' border: 1px solid black;border-collapse: collapse;'>&6</td>
                                            <td style=' border: 1px solid black;border-collapse: collapse;'>&7</td>
                                            <td style=' border: 1px solid black;border-collapse: collapse;'>&8</td>
                                        </tr>",
                                            tt_data.tt_userid,
                                            tt_data.tt_fullname,
                                            tt_data.tt_createddate,
                                            tt_data.tt_lastlogon, 
                                            tt_data.tt_needdisable,
                                            tt_data.tt_needdelete,
                                            tt_data.tt_disable,
                                            tt_data.tt_days,
                                            color
) SKIP.
```

And then your program needs to set the color variable based on whatever logic you need.

You could also match "normal" variables and the &-syntax of SUBSTITUTE:

```
DEFINE VARIABLE cColor AS CHARACTER   NO-UNDO.
DEFINE VARIABLE iInt   AS INTEGER     NO-UNDO.

cColor = "black".
iInt = 12.

MESSAGE  SUBSTITUTE("This is a color " + cColor + " and a number &1", iInt).
```

Comment: Thanks Jensd for the help. But still I am not getting it. I tried using the IF statement, but it shows incorrect syntax. This could be due to my limited knowledge in Progress.

Comment: Mistake by me, i missed the THEN part of then IF-statement.